# SQL Query to display % Change

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with sample data represented by Table 1 below. How do I write an SQL query to display them in either Table 2 or Table 3 format?

```
Table 1                         Table 2                      
Date        |  Value            Year  |  Week  |  Total Value  |  % Change               
------------+-------            ------+-----+--|---------------|----------
19/12/2011  |  60               2012  |    1   |      295      |  656.41%               
20/12/2011  |  49               2012  |    0   |       39      |  -80.98%               
21/12/2011  |  42               2012  |   52   |      205      |  -41.76%               
22/12/2011  |  57               2011  |   51   |      352      |                 
23/12/2011  |  88 
24/12/2011  |  18               Table 3                    
25/12/2011  |  38               Year  |  Week  |  SUM1  |  Year  |  Week  |  SUM2  |  % Change
26/12/2011  |  16               ------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------
27/12/2011  |  66               2012  |    1   |   295  |  2012  |    0   |   39   |  656.41%
28/12/2011  |  21               2012  |    0   |    39  |  2011  |   52   |  205   |  -80.98%
29/12/2011  |  79               2011  |   52   |   205  |  2011  |   51   |  352   |  -41.76%              
30/12/2011  |  7                2011  |   51   |   352  |    
31/12/2011  |  16
01/01/2012  |  39
02/01/2012  |  17
03/01/2012  |  86 
04/01/2012  |  55
05/01/2012  |  82
06/01/2012  |  0
07/01/2012  |  9
08/01/2012  |  46
```

Comment: Why do you want to display the data in the format of another table? Why not just view/access that table?

Comment: @SpeedCrazy - possibly he wants to show the calculations?

Comment: @louis - how do you calculate the % change? Which numbers are you comparing?

Comment: In that case i would do it in php(or whatever language you are acessing this from, php is just my forte). Im not sure that can be done in sql.

Comment: Here is the SQLite page on [Date and Time Functions.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)  You can find the syntax to select a range between 2011/1/1 and 2011/12/31 without having to calculate the number of second in a year yourself.

Comment: The above example is extremely simplified, and the actual data set is a lot more complicated. I would like to explore whether SQL can resolve my issue better, and decide again whether I should manage the data outside the database. As mentioned, my objective is to reformat the data in Table 1 into either formats illustrated by Table 2 or Table 3. I thought the % change formula is quite straight forward so I didn't mention. It's simply current/previous - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference would be to run 1 query to aggregate Table 1 to the year/week level and then do the "% change" in another language, depending on your environment. However, if you truly needed a SQL-only solution, you could do something like this.

```
create table t1 as
    select year(Date) as year, week(Date) as week, sum(Value) as totalvalue
    from table1
    group by year(Date) as year, week(Date) as week
    order by Date desc
;

select a.year, a.month, a.totalvalue,
(a.totalvalue-b.totalvalue)/b.totalvalue as pct_change
from (
  select year, month, totalvalue, 
  case when week>1 then week-1 else 52 end as prevweek,
  case when week>1 then year else year-1 end as prevyear
  from t1
  ) a
    left outer join t1 b
    on a.prevweek=b.week and a.prevyear =b.year
;
```

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to do the pct_change outside of SQL, but my trouble lies with my poor knowledge of SQL! I never came across "CASE" in SQL and I'll read up a little more and adapt it to my solution!